# Bug na Div do Google Maps Api V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

O meu Google Maps, quando está no zoom "global" e eu utilizo o draggable, ele some, como se fosse algum bug na div.

> **VISÃO GLOBAL, SEM USAR O DRAGGABLE.**
>
> [image: MAIN]
>
> **ARRASTANDO O MAPA, NA VISÃO GLOBAL.** [image: DRAGGABLE]

**CÓDIGO CSS:**

> ```
> html,
> body,
> #map {
>     height: 100%;
>     margin: 0;
>     padding: 0;
> }
> ```

**CÓDIGO HTML:**

> ```
> <header></header>
>
> <div id="map"></div>
>
> <main></main>
> <footer></footer>
> ```

**CÓDIGO JS:**

> ```
>   const MAP_DOM = document.getElementById('map');
>     const GOOGLE_MAPS = new google.maps.Map(MAP_DOM, {
>         id: "NeorisMapDefault",
>         center: new google.maps.LatLng({lat: -15, lng: -1}),
>         zoom: 2,
>         disableDefaultUI: true,
>         noClear: false,
>         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
>         draggable: false,
>     });
> ```

Comment: Não entendo muito da API, mas porque vc não bloqueia o Drag vertical quando estiver com Zoom Global?

Comment: @hugocsl porque pode ter marker perto do outro, ai não dará para clicar. Pois um irá sobrepor o outro.